# print не выводит число. Просто пустой терминал

Tags: python

```
x = y = 999 
z = []
z1 = 0

while y > 100:
    c = x * y
    if str(c) == str(c)[::-1] and c > z1:
        z1 = c
        z.clear()
        z.append([x,y])
    else:
        x -= 1
        x = 999

print(z,z1)
```

Comment: У вас `y` нигде не уменьшается, по этому `y > 100` всегда выполняется -> бесконечный цикл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в ваш код следующее, работает без отказно:

```
for i in range(100):
    pass
```

В вашем же примере `while y > 100:` - условие всегда будет True, поскольку в самом цикле вы не переопределяете переменную `y`. К тому же она у вас = 999.

Comment: Для такой конструкции специально ведь придумали короткий вариант `for i in range (100):`

Comment: спасибо изменил